# How to implicity rebuild children in the view so that they trigger componentWillMount?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a view, with view children:

```
render() {
 return (
   <View>
      <Child1/>
      <Child2/>
   </View>
 )
}
```

Now, if I place console log in `componenWillMount` method of these children, it will only trigger once, whenever I render my parent component first. However, I would like to have ability to implicitly rerender (so that they actually get initialised - and their `componentWillMount` will trigger again) them. Is this possible to do with React Native?

Comment: you want to update the child ? you can pass props to them like `<child data={data}/>` , when you change data the child should re render

Comment: rendering and mounting are two different thing. Mount always occurs once and render occurs whenever there is change in state or props data. componentWillMount is mounting function and componentWillUpdate is the function called before rerendering.

Answer (score 0):

Pass states to the component make that when thats states changes, the component is re-rendered so you could pass to the view a state that when you want to re-render it, it'll do. 
The state is passed by props. 
But anyway, if I'm not wrong, it only will be re-rendered but won't call componentWillMount, instead of it,  it will call

> componentWillReceiveProps()

That's all I know, I hope it works you. (And sorry my bad english)